# How to update and add module nginx debian

Tags: nginx, debian, update

How to update nginx with adding module without deleting old nginx files/configs?

I installed nginx with apt-get install, i tried install by downloading tar.gz from nginx site but it doesnt gave any effect.

I'm using debian 6.0.2 squeeze

I would be grateful for advice.

Best Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want new modules, you'll have to recompile your nginx. If you want to install it from source, you'll have to remove the Debian package first. Here's a short tutorial for you. I'm performing everything as root user in the following:

Create a backup of your configuration files:

```
mkdir ~/nginx-config-backup && cp -r /etc/nginx/* ~/nginx-config-backup
```

Remove previous nginx installation:

```
apt-get remove nginx*
```

You'll need this to build nginx from source:

```
apt-get install build-essentials
```

The directory where we'll put the source files:

```
cd /usr/local/src
```

Get latest development version of nginx:

```
wget http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.3.9.tar.gz
tar -zxvf nginx-1.3.9.tar.gz
mv nginx-1.3.9 nginx
rm -f nginx-1.3.9.tar.gz
```

Get latest PCRE version:

```
cd ../../lib
wget ftp://ftp.csx.cam.ac.uk/pub/software/programming/pcre/pcre-8.31.tar.gz
tar -zxvf pcre-8.31.tar.gz
mv pcre-8.31 pcre
rm -f pcre-8.31.tar.gz
```

Get latest OpenSSL version:

```
wget http://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
tar -zxvf openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
mv openssl-1.0.1c openssl
rm -f openssl-1.0.1c.tar.gz
```

Get latest zlib version:

```
git clone git://github.com/madler/zlib.git
```

Now I download two example modules for nginx:

```
cd ../includes
git clone git://github.com/masterzen/nginx-upload-progress-module.git
git clone git://github.com/gnosek/nginx-upstream-fair.git
```

Back to nginx; we configure our installation and compile + install it:

```
cd ../src/nginx
./configure
  --prefix=/usr/local
  --sbin-path=/usr/local/sbin
  --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
  --pid-path=/var/run/nginx.pid
  --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock
  --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log
  --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log
  --user=nginx
  --group=nginx
  --with-debug
  --with-file-aio
  --with-http_gzip_static_module
  --with-http_realip_module
  --with-http_ssl_module
  --with-md5=/usr/local/lib/openssl
  --with-md5-asm
  --with-openssl=/usr/local/lib/openssl
  --with-sha1=/usr/local/lib/openssl
  --with-sha1-asm
  --with-pcre=/usr/local/lib/pcre
  --with-pcre-jit
  --with-zlib=/usr/local/lib/zlib
  --without-http_browser_module
  --without-http_geo_module
  --without-http_limit_req_module
  --without-http_limit_conn_module
  --without-http_memcached_module
  --without-http_referer_module
  --without-http_split_clients_module
  --without-http_ssi_module
  --without-http_upstream_ip_hash_module
  --without-http_userid_module
  --without-http_uwsgi_module
  --add-module=/usr/local/include/nginx-upload-progress-module
  --add-module=/usr/local/include/nginx-upstream-fair
make
make install
```

Don't forget to clean up everything:

```
cd /usr/local
rm -rf
  src/nginx
  include/nginx-upload-progress-module
  include/nginx-upstream-fair
  lib/pcre
  lib/zlib
  lib/openssl
```

You'll now have a working nginx binary at `/usr/sbin/nginx`. Also make sure to update your `init`-script (at `/etc/init.d/nginx`) for nginx. Here's—as an example—my personal `init`-script:

https://github.com/Fleshgrinder/nginx-sysvinit-script